# Anybody have problems to access some apple website sections (ej: https://iforgot.apple.com/) with linux browsers

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I found trying to access to some apple websites sections (ej: https://iforgot.apple.com/) with a linux browser, i got  502 Bad Gateway error

[image: 502 Bad Gateway]

These error appears with:

- Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Firefox Quantum 64.0

I ask to Apple support and they told me that they don't have problems because the user Macs.

Comment: It's working for my Windows and Mac browsers.  The problem is on your side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is having problems with linux web browsers, not browsers running under macOS.

Comment: @IconDaemon It is a problem with Apple software so on topic for that - but I suspect off topic as due to questioners setup

Comment: Conceivably, this is to access an iCloud or AppleID account and Apple has identified [minimum system requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230).  Note, that Linux is not listed.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939

Answer (score 2):

Apple is blocking Linux useragent strings.  Change yours and the page(s) will load with no problem.  On Firefox browse to about:config, create a new string "general.useragent.override" then borrow a different useragent string of a browser Apple does not block.  I chose this one at random:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; fi-fi) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3
```

Comment: This also implies that most of the comments to the original question are wrong: change the user agent in your Safari browser to something Linuxy and you are probably going to be rejected too.

This is simply outrageous, and quite possibly the result of Apple trying to thwart Android users (or worse, converts; Android == Linux).